# Given K how do represent all of it's Binary Numbers

Tags: python

I was asked a question that I could not solve.

The question was essentially.

> given `k` is one and our output is `['0','1']`, given that `k` is two and our output is `['00','01','10','11']`

So essentially k represents the number of binary values to represent. If k is three we would want a list of binary numbers from 0-7, k is four we would want a list of binary numbers from 0-16.

For me I got lost on how to program it dynamically so given a number k we get our desired output.

Comment: Hint: Recursion.

Comment: Essentially, you want a binary representation for all numbers between `0` and `2^k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output grows exponentially with k, I'd recommend an iterable.

```
from itertools import product

def binary_numbers(k):
    return product('01', repeat=k)
```

From there you can do what you need with it.

```
for x in binary_numbers(3):
    print(''.join(x))
```

> 000
> 001
> 010
> 011
> 100
> 101
> 110
> 111

Answer (score 1):

These are binary representations of all numbers with the given number of digits. So iterate those numbers and format them as binary with padded zeroes. You can use [the format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for this, for instance with an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
def binary_numbers(k):
    return [f"{i:0>{k}b}" for i in range(1 << k)]
```

If you are supposed to do this with recursion, and not formatting of numbers into binary, then maybe this:

```
def binary_numbers(k):
    if k == 0:  # base case
        return [""]
    return [s + dig for s in binary_numbers(k-1) for dig in "01"]
```